# cuCtxCreate Fails with CUDA_ERROR_INVALID_DEVICE

Tags: cuda, cuda-context

I am getting CUDA_ERROR_INVALID_DEVICE error when creating a cuda context via cuCtxCreate.

My code is creating a context and getting device from it and creating a new context.

Any idea why I can't create another context?

```
#include<cuda.h>
#include<assert.h>

int main(){
        cuInit(0);
        CUcontext ctx;
        CUdevice device;

        CUdevice dev2;
        CUcontext c2;

        assert(cuDeviceGet(&device,0) == 0 );
        assert(cuCtxCreate(&ctx, 0, device) == 0);
        assert(cuCtxGetDevice(&dev2) == 0);
        assert(cuCtxCreate(&c2,0,dev2) == 0);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure `device==dev2` here, so you are effectively creating two contexts for a single device from a single host thread.  Why do you want to do this?

Comment: 2 threads can create different contexts on the same device. Then why not one thread create two different contexts? I am doing it to build a performance analysis f/w. I want to create a context on which performance analysis events live and don't get destroyed by user code destroying a context.

Comment: Have you verified that the device is not in exclusive mode?

Comment: Yes, that was the case. It worked find on a device which was not in exclusive mode.

Answer (score 3):

The problem was that the user had the device in exclusive mode, which prohibits creating two contexts on the single device.